# jquery changing position of div

Tags: jquery, position

I want to change position fixed/relative of a div on scrolling down/up
working fine locally but not working on server

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>100)
        {
            $("#searchBar").css({
                'position':'fixed',
                'top':'0px',
                'left':$("#wrapper").offset().left+1,
                'width':$("#wrapper").width()
            });
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop()<=100)
        {
            $("#searchBar").css({
                'position':'relative',
                'left':'0px'
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should clear the cache and verify the paths of jQuery library file and your js file

Comment: Get rid of your second `if` condition. That `if (...)` should be replaced with `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Server uses different id for elements. So try getting the id from the server with this.

Your `$("#searchBar")` should be `$("[id$=searchBar]")`, and `$("#wrapper")` should be `$("[id$=wrapper]")`.
This worked for me perfectly.